# Validate CSV file content in ActionScript

Tags: csv, actionscript

What's the best way to validate a CSV file containing email addresses in actionscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to start with one thing at a time:

1. [Load](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#includeExamplesSummary) and [parse](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split%28%29) the csv (alternatively you can use a [library](http://code.google.com/p/csvlib/))
2. Traverse the data and validate using [regular expressions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html#includeExamplesSummary)

You should be able to put together a bit of code by simply using the examples linked.